# SQL Server statement with "group by"

Tags: php, sql-server

I am writing a SQL Server statement to draw some data from 2 tables like this:-

```
$resume_full_name = "select * from [user] 

        left join [department]
        on [user].[departid] = [department].[departid]
        where id = '$value'                     
        order by [department].[departid] DESC";
```

and it works properly. However, when I try to add `GROUP BY [department].[departid]`, wherever this phase I put, it gives error.

> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. (severity 15) in
>   D:\project\true2\admin\page\ur\list.php on line 86 Warning:
>   mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in
>   D:\project\true2\admin\page\ur\list.php on line 86 Warning:
>   mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result
>   resource in D:\project\true2\admin\page\ur\list.php on line 88

Actually, do mssql suppport `Group By`? if not, how can we group things together? Thanks

Comment: Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. (severity 15) in D:\project\true2\admin\page\ur\list.php on line 86

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in D:\project\true2\admin\page\ur\list.php on line 86

Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in D:\project\true2\admin\page\ur\list.php on line 88

Comment: You can't add `group by` behind `order by`?

Comment: when I wrote:
SELECT [department].[departmentid] from [user] 
LEFT JOIN [department]
on [user].[departid] = [department].[departmentid]         WHERE id = '$single_allowed_userid'      
GROUP BY [department].[departmentid]
ORDER BY [department].[departmentid] DESC";

it gives no error, but the result is like this:
(13)
(25)
(25)
(5)
(13)
(5)

it actually has not group, and all departmentid appears twice...
how can I amend the sql statement so that it can group to 13, 25 and 5?

Comment: Please update your question and specifically the query part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does support `GROUP BY`, but you cannot `SELECT *` at the top, you have to apply an *aggregate function* (e.g. `SUM` or `AVG`) to some other field on which the aggregate of grouped rows will be shown.

Comment: when I wrote: SELECT [department].[departmentid] from [user] LEFT JOIN [department] on [user].[departid] = [department].[departmentid]  WHERE id = '$single_allowed_userid'  GROUP BY [department].[departmentid] ORDER BY [department].[departmentid] DESC"; it gives no error, but the result is like this: (13) (25) (25) (5) (13) (5) it actually has not group, and all departmentid appears twice... how can I amend the sql statement so that it can group to 13, 25 and 5?

Comment: @Ham Can you please attempt to model your data on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Then I would be able to give you the query you need.